# Winforms - How to alternate the color of rows in a ListView control?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, listview

Using C# Winforms (3.5).

Is it possible to set the row colors to automatically alternate in a listview?

Or do I need to manually set the row color each time a new row is added to the listview?

Based on a [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ms750769(VS.85).aspx) article the manual method would look like this:

```
//alternate row color
if (i % 2 == 0)
{
    lvi.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
}
else
{
    lvi.BackColor = Color.Beige;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, zebra striping may or may not make your table any easier to read according to this A List Apart article. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/zebrastripingdoesithelp/

Comment: +1 - Great article @Timothy.  I'll go with Zebra striping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid that is the only way in Winforms. XAML allows this through use of styles though.

Answer (score 8):

Set the ListView OwnerDraw property to true and then implement the DrawItem handler :

```
    private void listView_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
        if ((e.ItemIndex%2) == 1)
        {
            e.Item.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(230, 230, 255);
            e.Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = true;
        }
    }

    private void listView_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
```

This example is a simple one, you can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know WPF allows to set style on any control using `<Styles/>`
But in winforms I'm afraid may be that's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= listView.Items.Count - 1; i = (i + 2))
        {
            listView.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
        }
```

Set the main background in the properties menu then use this code to set the alternate color.

Answer (score -1):

You can also take advantage of owner drawing, rather than setting properties explicitly. Owner drawing is less vulnerable to item reordering.

Here is how to do this in [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) (a 3rd party component offering both free and extended versions) - its a matter of simply handling a `DrawItemBackground` event:

```
private void ListViewOnDrawItemBackground(object sender, BetterListViewDrawItemBackgroundEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if ((eventArgs.Item.Index & 1) == 1)
    {
        eventArgs.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, eventArgs.ItemBounds.BoundsOuter);
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Set the ListView OwnerDraw property to true and then implement the DrawItem handler. Have a look here : [Winforms - How to alternate the color of rows in a ListView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866730/winforms-how-to-alternate-the-color-of-rows-in-a-listview-control/47786642#47786642)